Multiple SPA application in subdirectories + SPA in root directory
I cant figure out how to have this structure of locations working for my app
/ <- base location serves angular "base" app
/cms/en <- multiple language directories serve localized angular "cms" app
/cms/nl
/cms/de ... etc
and my config kinda works, but only until i open base app... it's like my application "hijacks" routing, never hits nginx locations and just serves 404 for page.com/cms/nl.
Before loading page.com in browser, my page.com/cms/nl location works as it should
Base app has wildcard route for not matched urls.
it's some cacheing issue, i tried so many thing i'am totally lost now
how would i fix it ?
my server block looks like this
server{
    server_name page.com;
    root /var/www/page.com;

    location /cms/fr {
        alias /var/www/html/page.com/cms/fr;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cmspl;

        # kill cache
        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
    }

    location /cms/en {
        alias /var/www/html/page.com/cms/en;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cmsen;
    }

    location /cms/nl {
        alias /var/www/html/page.com/cms/nl;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @cmsnl;
    }

    location @cmspl {
        rewrite /cms/fr/(.*)$ /cms/fr/index.html?/$1 last;
    }

    location @cmsen {
        rewrite /cms/en/(.*)$ /cms/en/index.html?/$1 last;
    }

    location @cmsnl {
        rewrite /cms/nl/(.*)$ /cms/nl/index.html?/$1 last;
    }

    location / {
        #add_header content-type text/plain;
        #return 200 'location base';
        proxy_pass           http://127.0.0.1:4811;
        proxy_set_header     Host            $host;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        proxy_no_cache 1;
        # even if cached, don't try to use it
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;

        add_header Last-Modified $date_gmt;
        add_header Cache-Control 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
        if_modified_since off;
        expires off;
        etag off;
    }
}


there will be routing set in your base app.  (this is client-side routing... while the URL is updated, the browser does not perform navigation)  You should include your app's route definitions.  (That's what it sounds like anyway.  To test just hit "reload" button while your desired URL is showing in the browser.)

that wasn't it - my problem was service worker -i had to add this "!/grid**" to navigationUrls in ngsw-config.json - now my application ignores that directory and everything works fine :)
